# JSONModel Error: "Type not allowed" works on iOS 7 not on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, jsonmodel

I have two classes

=== PEOPLE ====

```
@protocol People @end

@interface People : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *userName;

@end
```

=== PEOPLE CONTAINER ====

```
@interface PeopleContainer : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) People       *people;

@end
```

The code fails at this line:

```
PeopleContainer *peopleContainer = [[PeopleContainer alloc] initWithDictionary:peopleContainerDict error:&err];
```

giving error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Type not allowed', reason: 'Account type not supported for ChatRoomContainer.account'
*** First throw call stack: (0x2243012 0x1725e7e 0x34e90 0x76ef5 0xf18cf8 0xe8075a 0xe4e453 0xe4e164 0xedaa31 0x50fe53f 0x5110014 0x51012e8 0x5101450 0x53d9e72 0x53c1daa) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The problem is that it works perfectly fine with iOS >7 but not on iOS 6.1
(I have tested it on both simulator and device).

Can someone help?

EDIT:

Here is the ACCOUNT CLASS

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol Account @end

@interface Account : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *userName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *emailAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *password;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *phoneNumber;

@end
```

And the other class CHAT ROOM CONTAINER containing the ACCOUNT CLASS

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "Account.h"
#import "Friend.h"
#import "ChatRoom.h"

@interface ChatRoomContainer : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) Account           *account;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<ChatRoom> *chatRooms;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Friend>   *friends;

@end
```

I send out a request to our server using

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if (completion) {
         if (!error) {
             NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
             NSDictionary *errorDict = [responseDict objectForKey:@"error"];
             NSDictionary *warningDict = [responseDict objectForKey:@"warning"];
             NSDictionary *result = [responseDict objectForKey:@"result"];
             NSLog(@"RESULT\n====\n%@\n====\n",responseDict);
             if(errorDict != nil && ![[NSNull null] isEqual:errorDict]) {
                 NSError* err = nil;
                 CustomError *error = [[CustomError alloc] initWithDictionary:errorDict error:&err];
                 completion(NO, nil, error, nil);
             } else {

                 NSDictionary *chatRoomContainerDict = [result objectForKey:@"chatRoomContainer"];
                 NSError* err = nil;
                 ChatRoomContainer *chatRoomContainer = [[ChatRoomContainer alloc] initWithDictionary:chatRoomContainerDict error:&err];
                 if(!err) {
                     CustomWarning *warning = [[CustomWarning alloc] initWithDictionary:warningDict error:&err];
                     completion(!error, chatRoomContainer, nil, warning);
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"ERROR WHILE PARSING CHAT ROOM CONTAINER JSON DICT!!! %@", [err userInfo]);
                     completion(!error, nil, nil, nil);
                 }
             }
         } else {
             if(![AuxiliaryHelper connectedToInternet]) {
                 NSLog(@"NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
                 completion(NO, nil, [[CustomError alloc] initWithErrorType:ErrorTypeNoInternetConnection], nil);
             } else {
                 DLog(@"INTERNAL SERVER ERROR!!!");
                 completion(NO, nil, [[CustomError alloc] initWithErrorType:ErrorTypeInternalServerError], nil);
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: All JSONMOdel unit tests pass on iOS7; your problem must be very specific. Do you have a more complete source code to show?

Comment: @IcanZilb It works perfectly on iOS7 when I run it on iOS 6 and 6.1 simulator or the device it crashes. I have updated the question to include the actual source code. Plus I have "- (NSString *)debugDescription" and "- (NSString *)description" methods in Account class.

Comment: @IcanZilb Do you have any idea about this? I was debugging more and its failing in Line 337 in JSONModel.m file "if ([valueTransformer respondsToSelector:selector]) {" and then throwing out an exception! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm on the road, can't really have a look right now, sorry

Comment: @IcanZilb I fixed my problem by renaming Account class to Acct. Now it works on iOS6 as well. But am still not sure what caused the problem.

Comment: xo ... strange ... the class name "Account" was causing the trouble? Maybe there's an Apple class called account somewhere behind the scenes and you clashed with it

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem. maybe the error came from your class "Account,chatRoom,etc". 
I wrote 
`objc
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger goodId;`

into
`objc
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger* goodId;`

so just check U class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: my error come from miswrite "@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger goodId;"into "@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger* goodId;".so may something similar was appeared in U class